# Tableview section appearing after deleting all rows deleted from section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview and its has 2 sections.Based on numberOfRowsInsection,the sectionheaderview setting in viewForHeaderInSection.And this view is coming from xib.Now my problem is after deleting all rows from any section, the header view still appearing,though passing 0.0f in heightForHeaderInSection,and returning nil value from viewForHeaderInSection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just pass 1.0 in heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: by default i am passing 0.f

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;
    
    if (section == 0) {
        if ([myItems1 count]) {
            height = 45.0;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ([myItems count]) {
            height = 45.0;
        }
    }
    return height;
}

Comment: -(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f,                                                                                  0.f,320.f,22.f)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    if (section ==0 &&[myItems1 count]==0) {
        view = nil;
    }
    else   if (section ==1 &&[myItems1 count]==0) {
        view = nil;
    }
    return view;

Comment: Plz let me know whats the issue

Comment: Change method with this-

Comment: Change method with this-- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     CGFloat height = 1.0f;
     if (section == 0)
     {
         if ([myItems1 count])
         {
             height = 45.0;
         }
         else
             height = 1.0;
     }
     else
     {
         if ([myItems count])
         {
             height = 45.0;
         }
         else
             height = 1.0;
     }
     
     return height;
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72202/discussion-between-user716937-and-ravi-gautam).